# Datatable Excel and PDF button not working

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I don't know why my Datatable button are not working. **Copy** and **CSV** Buttons works well, but **Excel** and **PDF** did not work.

I have all npm modules installed, and i have all of them already imported

```
$ from 'jquery'
import 'jszip'
import 'datatables.net'
import 'datatables.net-bs'
import 'datatables.net-responsive'
import 'datatables.net-buttons'

import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js'
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js'
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js' 
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js'
```

And here is my Datatable config:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
                    responsive: true,
                    "language": datatableBR,
                    "dom": '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgt<"row"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6"p>>',
                    "buttons": [
                { extend: 'copy'},
                {extend: 'csv'},
                {extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile'},
                {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile'}
            ]
                })
```

Anyone knows why these two buttons don't work?

Thanks a lot!!

**@EDIT - Solution**

I think datatables.net and datatables.net-bs was entering in conflict. I'm using only datatables.net-bs now.
I installed too "jszip" from NPM using --save.

=)

Answer (score 6):

You have missing libraries. According to official documentation, you need these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

For more information, please check this official document: **[link](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export)**

Comment: Thanks man, using CDN it works well, but i wanted to use Import with webpack instead of CDN links into index.html. But thanks for support! I already solved my problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to include below script to run excel and pdf.

For excel add this script:
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js'

For pdf add these script:
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/pdfmake.min.js'

Answer (score 0):

The PDF Libraries needed are currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Source: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export

Datatables PDF Info: https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf